# Using Conditional Formatting with Icon Sets with six conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, vba

I'm using Conditional Formatting, I've been playing around with Conditional Formatting for a couple of days but I can't get the response I'm looking for.

I'm wanting a colored circle to appear in cell based on the marks entered. But the problem is I have six conditions but Excel supports only five I think. Is this possible?

```
0-20  red color circle
21-39 green color circle
40-54 blue color circle
55-64 yellow color circle
65-79 orange color circle
80-100 pink color circle
```

[image: Example - icon style base conditional formatting]

Comment: @pnuts  yes. same cell.

Comment: I am not familiar in VBA. I used conditional formatting menu. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb407306(v=office.11).aspx  I read this but couldn't  find any solution.

Comment: This is a good question but could easily have been made a **great** question with some sample data together with row and column references or even an image of expected results that showed the row and column labels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are limited to Conditional Formatting rules with Icon Sets:

- and if you don't have to have circles, your 6 rules can be easily set up as in the image bellow
- if you need more than 4 colored circles in CF rules: [Create Your Own Excel Icon Set](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2013/09/03/create-your-own-excel-icon-set/)

If you can use VBA, the code bellow will create stylized circles similar to native CF circles

- Open VBA: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>
- Create a new module: menu item **Insert** > **Module** and paste the code
- Click anywhere inside the first sub `testIcons()` and press <kbd>F5</kbd> to run it

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub testIcons()
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   setIcon Sheet1.UsedRange
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Sub setIcon(ByRef rng As Range)
   Dim cel As Range, sh As Shape, adr As String

   For Each sh In rng.Parent.Shapes
      If InStrB(sh.Name, "$") > 0 Then sh.Delete
   Next: DoEvents
   For Each cel In rng
      If Not IsError(cel.Value2) Then
         If Val(cel.Value2) > 0 And Not IsDate(cel) Then
           adr = cel.Address
           Set sh = Sheet1.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, cel.Left + 5, cel.Top + 2, 10, 10)
           sh.ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset38: sh.Name = adr
           sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = getCelColor(Val(cel.Value2))
           sh.Fill.Solid
         End If
      End If
   Next
End Sub

Public Function getCelColor(ByRef celVal As Long) As Long
   Select Case True
      Case celVal < 21:    getCelColor = RGB(222, 0, 0):    Exit Function
      Case celVal < 40:    getCelColor = RGB(0, 111, 0):    Exit Function
      Case celVal < 55:    getCelColor = RGB(0, 0, 255):    Exit Function
      Case celVal < 64:    getCelColor = RGB(200, 200, 0):  Exit Function
      Case celVal < 80:    getCelColor = RGB(200, 100, 0):  Exit Function
      Case celVal <= 100:  getCelColor = RGB(200, 0, 200):  Exit Function
   End Select
End Function
```

---

[image]

---

**Note**:

- The VBA code should be used with small data
- It can generates a large number of shapes which will make all other operations slow

A test with approx 1,000 rows and 20 cols: Total circles **19,250**; duration:  **47.921875 seconds**

---

**Edit**: made 2 updates to sub `setIcon()`

1. Self-cleaning
2. If the cell doesn't contain an error, it processes numeric values only

   - It excludes cells with text, empty cells, or dates
   - Thanks for the suggestion @EEM

Comment: How to overcome the empty cells?

Comment: I updated it to exclude empty cells (do you have any other shapes on the sheet? any other objects?)

Comment: Sara I made an important update: please update the code and run it again to cleanup any previous circles - this version refreshes all circles and removes any pre-existing ones (self-cleaning)

Comment: Nice way to tidy up. Wouldn't want to start reproducing the old XL2007 bug that split and stacked CF rules on top of each other.

Comment: @Jeeped: lol - it WAS the "CF rules" horror when I saw it happening in the first tests, so I decided to just remove them all in spite of another tedious loop

Comment: @paul bica nice solution. However, the code actually is adding Shapes to every cell that is not blank _(including those with labels)_, to correct this replace this line:  

 `If Len(cel.Value2) > 0 Then`  

with these:  

`Dim dCllVal As Double, blCllNA As Boolean  
        
    Rem Validate Cell Contents  
    dCllVal = 0  
    blCllNA = False  
    If Len(cel.Value2) = 0 Then blCllNA = True  
    On Error Resume Next  
    dCllVal = cel.Value2  
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then blCllNA = True  
    On Error GoTo 0  
    If Not (blCllNA) Then`  _pardon the format, don't know how to do in comments_

Comment: @EEM: thanks - I'm always trying to improve, but: 1. what do you mean by _cell label_? 2. I think you are trying to determine if a cell.Value2 with a length of 0 contains a double? The first question is more important - how do you define the label

Comment: Hi @paulbica – what I meant is a cell with a _Non-Numeric_ value.
Your code only checks whether the cell is empty at  `If Len(cel.Value2) > 0 Then`, so if the cell value is _non-numeric_ complies with the condition, therefore when the code later uses the value of the cell to retrieve the color to apply at `sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = getCelColor(Val(cel.Value2))` the result of `Val(cel.Value2)` is 0 then a red shape is added to the cell. To see this, in Sheet1 fill some cells with _“strings”_ or _“labels”_ and run the code you shall see the shapes are added to all _non-empty_ cells.

Comment: The changes proposed check for both conditions: If cell is empty using the length of cell value and if cell value is non-numeric by assigning the cell value to `dCllVal` variable _(data type double)_ so if the value of the cell is non-numeric it gives an error. The variable `blCllNA` captures the results of both validations

Comment: @EEM: good point - I updated the answer to check for errors, empty cells, and cells with dates. I didn't use your proposed checks because I restrict error handling (the use of _On Error_) as much as possible, only to cases where there is no other way of performing validation, like determining if an array is empty for example, or if data validation rules exist or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89520/discussion-between-eem-and-paul-bica).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with VBA.

The Setup, draw an oval shape and drag the cell down to copy it. Once done, then you can enter the values or the formulas.

[image]

Once you run the code the shapes will change color.

[image]

The Code

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim r As String, rng As Range

    I = 1
    For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes

        If sh.Name = "Oval " & I Then

            r = sh.TopLeftCell.Address    'find the range of the button clicked.

            Set rng = Range(r)

            Select Case rng

            Case Is < 21
                ActiveSheet.Shapes(sh.Name).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 255

            Case Is < 40
                ActiveSheet.Shapes(sh.Name).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 5287936

            Case Is < 55
                ActiveSheet.Shapes(sh.Name).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 12611584

            Case Is < 65
                ActiveSheet.Shapes(sh.Name).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 65535

            Case Is < 80
                ActiveSheet.Shapes(sh.Name).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 51)

            Case Is < 101
                ActiveSheet.Shapes(sh.Name).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 204)

            Case Else
            End Select

            I = I + 1

        End If

    Next


End Sub
```

[Sample Workbook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByXxMRXssekca3lpRDNYRG5BU2c/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

VBA is the only way I know of doing this.  If you can cope with the whole cell being coloured then this might work for you:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error GoTo Finish
Application.EnableEvents = False

If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo Finish

If Target.Value = "" Then
    Target.Interior.Color = -4142 ' no colour
    GoTo Finish
ElseIf Target.Value < 21 Then
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'red
    GoTo Finish
ElseIf Target.Value < 40 Then
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 10 'green
    GoTo Finish
ElseIf Target.Value < 55 Then
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 23 'blue
GoTo Finish
ElseIf Target.Value < 65 Then
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 'yellow
    GoTo Finish
ElseIf Target.Value < 80 Then
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 45 'orange
    GoTo Finish
ElseIf Target.Value < 101 Then
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 7 ' pink
Else
    Target.ColorIndex = -4142
End If


Finish: Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

This will run when ever you change the value of a cell in the worksheet.  Because I'm lazy (and pretty mediocre at coding) it will only work when you update a single cell at a time, and it is running on the entire work sheet.  But it will give you a starting point to work from.