# Show icon only in conditional formatting, without the value of the cell

Tags: excel, vba

I borrowed the code below from a post on this site a few years ago by Paul Bica.
([Using Conditional Formatting with Icon Sets with six conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536860/using-conditional-formatting-with-icon-sets-with-six-conditions/32540611#32540611?newreg=7e3e1ad8132345cdbcdd4d3af1fc6281))

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub testIcons()
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   setIcon Sheet1.UsedRange
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Sub setIcon(ByRef rng As Range)
   Dim cel As Range, sh As Shape, adr As String

   For Each sh In rng.Parent.Shapes

      If InStrB(sh.Name, "$") > 0 Then sh.Delete
   Next: DoEvents
   For Each cel In rng
      If Not IsError(cel.Value2) Then
         If Val(cel.Value2) > 0 And Not IsDate(cel) Then
           adr = cel.Address
           Set sh = Sheet1.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, cel.Left + 5, cel.Top + 2, 10, 10)
           sh.ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset38: sh.Name = adr
           sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = getCelColor(Val(cel.Value2))
           sh.Fill.Solid
         End If
      End If
   Next
End Sub

Public Function getCelColor(ByRef celVal As Long) As Long
   Select Case True
      Case celVal = 1:    getCelColor = RGB(211, 211, 211):    Exit Function
      Case celVal = 2:    getCelColor = RGB(0, 0, 0):    Exit Function
      Case celVal = 3:    getCelColor = RGB(255, 0, 0):    Exit Function
      Case celVal = 4:    getCelColor = RGB(255, 153, 204):  Exit Function
      Case celVal = 5:    getCelColor = RGB(255, 255, 51):  Exit Function
      Case celVal = 6:    getCelColor = RGB(0, 204, 0):  Exit Function
   End Select
End Function
```

I would like to have it show the icons only without the value of the cell.

Comment: Can you just set the font color to white?

Comment: On the code you have `Not IsError(cel.Value2)` it is looking for a value in a cell. If you are interested on having the icon without a value (that is what I am understanding), just place `IsError(cel.Value2)`, removing the Not

Comment: Thanks for responding. 
 
@David Garcia Bodega..  You are correct in your assumption.  I tried your suggestion, but unfortunately it removed the icons and left the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with the number format of the cells being changed, I think after this line:

```
sh.Fill.Solid
```

you can put:

```
cel.NumberFormat = ";;;"
```

and that should effectively make the cell's content transparent<sup>1</sup> (match the cell's background colour).

Seems to work for me:

[image: Code output]

---

<sup>1</sup> Doesn't seem to work for cells containing errors (e.g. `#N/A`), but I think this is a non-issue as your code ignores error-containing cells.

Comment: Awesome.!!!  Thanks chillin.  I think that will work just fine for me.
Now..  the next question is how do I get this to work automatically when I input the number without having to run the code manually every time..??

Comment: @AndySearle, one approach might to be put the code in a sheet module's `Worksheet_Change` event procedure. In your case, you might add `testIcons` to the event code, which would mean whenever you change that sheet's cells, your `testIcons` procedure will run. I'm not sure if that's what you want, but that is just  an example.